# Faulting a CoreData relationship when fetching the main entity

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an entity with a number of to-many relationships. I present certain properties of the entity in a tableview, using a NSFetchedResultsController. Of all the relationships the entity has, the values of only 1 of the relationships are displayed (they are currently faulted in the cellforrowat... method). It seems to me that this could have a performance impact. Is it possible to fault a specific relationship at the time of creating the Fetch request, so that CoreData does not have to fetch the values when the table is being scrolled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the data model you're describing.  If you are only displaying members of one of your entity's to-many relationships as the content for the table's rows, then you can fetch only the properties on display in each of the visible rows using -setPropertiesToFetch: on your fetch request, like in the following example:

```
NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"title", @"thumbnailImage", nil];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];
[propertiesToFetch release];
```

However, if what you're describing is a list of entities, with one of the displayed elements in the table row being from a to-one relationship, you can use `-setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` like Barry suggests.  However, in that case I'd suggest denormalizing your data model and moving that property from being within a relationship to being directly within the original entity.  Traversing relationships is much more expensive than accessing properties.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would not assume that the default Core Data behavior is less performant than your proposed approach: without data to back up your efforts, optimization is almost certainly going to go awry.

That said, I believe [`-[NSFetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW9) will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could manually fault in objects, but I don't think you'll gain anything. Whether you fault in all the objects at once, or you fault them in one at a time as needed, each object is still going to be faulted in individually.

I have written apps that do exactly what you describe, fault in a large amount of data to display in a table view, and have never noticed a performance penalty. Remember, only the objects that correspond to table view cells that will be displayed will be faulted in.

In general, I'd say don't try to outsmart Core Data. It's got years of performance optimizations in it at this point. While, intuitively, it may seem like faulting in 100 objects would require 100 database queries, this is not necessarily the case.